# Facebook Share the older version of the article

Tags: social-network

I using facebook share to share my article to facebook.

Sometimes I edit my article title and image.

While I share it to facebook, the article title and image is still shows the older version of the article.

Anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: You can use one of the solutions from this article
http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clear the cache. The title and image will updated.